# Powershell Foreach multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I am trying to performing a foreach loop with multiple arrays without success.
I want to add users from a list as local administrators of computers they are logged Into invoking psexec.
The property CustomComputername is an extensionAttribute representing the Computername the user is logged on.

```
$array1= get-content "C:\list.txt"
$array2= foreach ($u in $array1)
{get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -eq $user} -Properties CustomComputername |
Select -expandproperty CustomComputername}

foreach ($Computer in $array2){
foreach ($u in $array 1)      {
Invoke-PsExec -ComputerName $Computer -Command "net localgroup administrators $u /add"
}
```

Above command adds every user to every computer.
How to add the single user to a single computer he's logged on?
I can't get it working, I'm still learning and I have not enough knowledge. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1= get-content "C:\list.txt"
$array2= foreach ($u in $array1)
{get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -eq $user} -Properties CustomComputername |
Select -expandproperty CustomComputername | %{@($user,$_)}}

foreach ($info in $array2){
Invoke-PsExec -ComputerName $info[1] -Command "net localgroup administrators $($info[0]) /add"
}
```